# Why is my neural network predicting -0 (PYTHON - backpropagation XOR)?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm working on developing a neural network from scratch. The issue seems to maybe be with my relu back-propagation. When I train the model it sometimes outputs -0 and sometimes outputs good predictions (relatively). Can someone tell me if I'm doing my back propagation incorrectly or if there's a reason why my relu would be predicting -0?

--
[edit]

Fixed the issue of predicting -0, but now it just predicts 0 for all inputs for the XOR. Can someone look over my backpropagation?

```
import numpy as np


# Each layer in our neural network
class NeuralLayer:
    def __init__(self, input_neurons, output_neurons):
        self.weights = np.random.randn(input_neurons, output_neurons)* np.sqrt(2. / input_neurons)
        self.bias = np.ones((1,output_neurons)) * 0.5

    # Two different activations, sigmoid by default
    def sigmoid(self, neurons):
        self.act = 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-neurons))
        return self.act
    
    def sigmoidBackward(self, grad):
        return grad * self.act * (1 - self.act)
    
    def relu(self, neurons):
        self.act = (neurons > 0)
        return neurons * self.act
    
    def reluBackward(self, grad):
        return grad * self.act

    # Forward pass for this layer
    def forward(self, input, activation):
        self.input = np.atleast_2d(input)
        if activation == 'sigmoid':
            return self.sigmoid(input @ self.weights + self.bias)
        else:
            return self.relu(input @ self.weights + self.bias)
        
    # backward pass for this layer
    def backward(self, grad, activation):
        
        if activation == 'sigmoid':
            grad = self.sigmoidBackward(np.atleast_2d(grad))
        else:
            grad = self.reluBackward(np.atleast_2d(grad))
        
        self.grad_weights = np.matmul(self.input.T, grad)
        self.grad_bias = grad.sum()
        return grad @ self.weights.T
    
    def step(self, step_size):
        self.weights -= step_size*self.grad_weights
        self.bias -= step_size*self.grad_bias

# Our neural net
class NeuralNetwork:
    
    # Dynamically create all layers 
    def __init__(self, input_neurons, hidden_neurons, layer_count, activation, output_neurons = 1):
        
        self.activation = activation
        
        # Used to ensure input neurons match inputted data
        self.neuron_safety = input_neurons
        assert layer_count >= 2 and output_neurons >= 1
        
        # Input layer
        self.layers = [NeuralLayer(input_neurons, hidden_neurons)]
                
        # Hidden Layers
        for i in range(layer_count - 2):
            self.layers.append(NeuralLayer(hidden_neurons, hidden_neurons))
            
        # Output layer
        self.layers.append(NeuralLayer(hidden_neurons, output_neurons))
    
    # Forward pass for each layer
    def forward(self, inp):
        
        assert inp.shape[0] == self.neuron_safety
        
        for layer in self.layers:
            inp = layer.forward(inp, self.activation)
            
        return inp 
    
    def backward(self, grad):
        for layer in reversed(self.layers):
            grad = layer.backward(grad, self.activation)
                                  
    def step(self, step_size = 0.01):
        for layer in self.layers:
            layer.step(step_size)
    
    # loss function - only 1 output neuron
    def meanSquaredError(self, preds, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.preds = preds
        return  (self.preds - self.labels)**2
    
    def meanSquaredErrorGrad(self):
        return 2 * (self.preds - self.labels)
```

```
# Create a neural network with 2 inputs, 2 hidden neurons in each layer, and 2 layers 
net = NeuralNetwork(2,16,4, 'relu')
epochs = 5000

# Input data (A,B) for XOR
X = np.array([[0,0],[1,1], [1,0],[0,1]])

# Expected output data 
Y = np.array([[0],[0],[1],[1]])


for i in range(epochs):
    preds = []
    for idx, x in enumerate(X):
        predictions = net.forward(x)
        preds.append(predictions)
        loss = net.meanSquaredError(predictions, Y[idx])
        loss_grad = net.meanSquaredErrorGrad()
        net.backward(loss_grad)
        net.step()

print("Model predicted: {}\nactual values: {} ".format(preds, Y.T))
```

Output:

```
Model predicted: [array([[-0.]]), array([[-0.]]), array([[1.]]), array([[-0.]])]
```

actual values: `[[0 0 1 1]]`

Sometimes the predictions are perfect, but most of the time at least one prediction will be -0

Comment: From the relu function, change the last line `return neurons * self.act` to `return np.maximum(neurons, 0)`. This can get rid of the negative.

Comment: This got rid of the -0 predictions, but it's still not making great predictions. For example, after that change I get : Model predicted: [array([[0.]]), array([[0.]]), array([[0.]]), array([[0.]])]
actual values: [[0 0 1 1]]  -  since it's only 4 points shouldn't it drastically over fit and predict almost perfect?

Comment: I don't know. I just quickly skim through the code. You don't get the perfect prediction probably because the randomness in the model. The model stuck in a local minimum or something.

Comment: Well, thanks for taking a look. I don't understand because using sigmoid I get good predictions, but relu not so much.. relu only predicts 0 for all results, but sigmoid will get very close to perfect. Is there a way to adjust for the randomness of the model?

Comment: I also spot the problem that your code is using mean square error, which is a loss function for regression. But your target is 0 and 1, which is binary.

Comment: What should I use? I just wanted to show that a basic neural network could learn a XOR gate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bias gradient is incorrect.  You are using `self.grad_bias = grad.sum()`.  This will compute the sum of the entire matrix.  It needs to be `self.grad_bias = grad.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)` to compute a `1 x output_neurons` array that will properly update the bias vector.  Otherwise, `grad.sum()` provides a single number that you are using to update all of your biases, which is not correct.

Also, make sure you update your forward pass for your ReLU to `np.maximum(neurons, 0)` as described in the comments.

```
    def relu(self, neurons):
        self.act = (neurons > 0)
        return np.maximum(neurons, 0)
```

The gradient of the activations will be 0 or 1 depending on which parts of the inputs were positive.

Finally, for the XOR problem you typically do not use ReLU as the activation for the output layer because it is not bounded between [0-1] as per the XOR problem.  The reason why you got good results with the sigmoid activation function is that the dynamic range of that activation function suits the XOR problem well.  As an experiment, you can modify the output layer to be sigmoid, and the hidden layers to be ReLU.  If you do this, you should get just as good a performance as using sigmoid all the way.

Comment: Thank you! Is it okay to round the predictions? For example, sigmoid outputs 0.978 for [1,0] or is that bad practice?

Comment: Perfectly fine to round if you are providing a final answer. Do not round if you are using backprop as you need the exact loss to properly compute the gradient. In this case, keep the final (rounded) answer separate from the raw output of the final sigmoid layer. The raw output should be used for the backward pass while the rounded answer is for your eyes only.